# How do I not prioritize pronunciation over comprehension when reading out loud?

Tags: pronunciation, reading

When I read an Italian text (this question is about reading out loud), what I focus on dictates how "well" I read it.

For example, if I focus on pronunciation, then my pronunciation is flawless, but I have absolutely no idea what I'm reading. If I focus on comprehension, my pronunciation goes into the toilet even though I have a significantly better idea of what I'm reading.

What practice techniques help improve the ability of native-level reading (where you read with "perfect" pronunciation / comprehension)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you describe is normal. I consider it an example of the [impossibility of (real) multitasking](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/3713/13937). That doesn't mean you can't do anything about it though. Here are a few things you can do:

- Instead of reading, use a **different technique to improve pronunciation**. The technique that I use most is known as [**shadowing**](https://oupeltglobalblog.com/2013/01/23/shadowing-a-useful-technique-for-autonomous-practice-of-listening-and-speaking/): you find an audio file or a video, put on a pair of headphones, and mimic the spoken words or dialogue while they are being spoken. If it is an extract from a film or a play, you should also try to mimic the intonation and emotions that are expressed in the dialogue. See also [Language Shadowing: A Superior Learning Method](https://www.mezzoguild.com/language-shadowing-a-superior-learning-method/) and the videos by Alexander Arguelles on YouTube. You would usually take (parts of) audio or video files that are only a few minutes long and "shadow" them several times before you move on to the next one.
- Find recordings of the texts you read and use the shadowing technique with these. (Shadowing does, strictly speaking, not require any text.)
- If you don't want to use audio or video, then take texts or excerpts that are roughly one page long and **slow down your reading tempo** so that you can get "into" the text and base your intonation (irony, surprise, scorn, etc. - if you are reading fiction) on your understanding of the text. You will probably need to repeat this a few times to reach the pronunciation you are aiming at.

Reading out loud is primarily a pronunciation exercise; it is not the best way on increase understanding.

Comment: I agree. If you can't get both, a decent pronunciation and a good text understanding, immediately in parallel, repeat reading the very same text until both aspects work, and your brain gets a chance to associate meaning and sound.